# Use functionality of device hub windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there a way that I could use data from device hub on windows phone 8? Device hub shows you all devices that are in your network, and would like to get that data for my application to connect to this device which is discovered in device hub...

Comment: Are you talking about connecting devices which are connected through bluetooth?

Comment: no.. if you are connected to wifi and go to device hub, all devices that are connected to the same wifi are shown...

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about [Nokia Device hub](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/nokia-device-hub-beta/e1454d4d-b646-4a79-bcc1-bab8bf08ae5a) ?
As far as I'm aware it's [being put to an end](http://www.wpcentral.com/microsoft-ends-device-hub-beta-available-lumia-cyan) and will be in the Lumia Cyan update.
Otherwise, I'm afraid there is no API. Aside from the [network changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh487166(v=vs.105).aspx) Api, you won't have much choice.

Comment: but how do then remote desktop apps work? they have to get devices in the network somehow, to connect to them...